# iTunes Connect error for archive uploaded from Xcode 6.3: contains invalid version of Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, app-store-connect

I built and uploaded my app to itunes connect using the release version of Xcode 6.3 last night but it was rejected as "invalid binary".  The email from App Review said I was using an invalid or beta version of Swift.
I would really appreciate any help or ideas about how to work around this problem.

I originally created the app in a release version of Xcode (6.1 I think) but then worked on it in the beta versions of 6.3 over the last month or so.  Could this be causing the "invalid binary" rejection, even though I built and uploaded the archive in the release version of 6.3?  If so, what can I do about it?

I have tried deleting derived data, revoking my certificates, and editing each of the app's source code files in the release version of 6.3 to see if that would help (it didn't).

Comment: Yesterday's 6.3 release is a beta?

Comment: My apologies.  My app store didn't tell me there was an update.  Now I know...

Comment: Are you using Swift 1.2?

Comment: I looked at the release notes and I don't believe I am using any new Swift 1.2 features.  For what it's worth, xcode 6.2 gets stuck on indexing when I try to build the app (xcode 6.3 builds it without a problem).

Answer (score 1):

You are likely using an old version of swift.  Inside Xcode there should be a menu option to "upgrade to latest version of swift"

This error can also occur if you are using a beta version of swift that is ahead of the app store.

If you are using a beta version of Xcode, open your project in the latest release version and try to build again. - You cannot submit apps compiled in beta to the app store.

If you are using old swift - try to figure out which menu option lets you upgrade.

Ah its this:
**"click the Edit menu, then choose Convert > To Swift 1.2."**